# Kafka-MongoDB source and sink connector

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I have created a 3 VM Kafka Cluster and installed mongoDB on each VM. Also, running kafka-mongoDB connector.
My source connector config on first VM is:

```
{
  "name": "source1",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
    "connection.uri": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "publish.full.document.only": true,
    "database": "Ecomm1",
    "collection": "orders"
  }
}
```

My Sink Connector config on Second & Third VMs is:

```
{
  "name": "sink1",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
    "topics": "Ecomm1.orders",
    "connection.uri": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": false,
    "database": "Ecomm",
    "collection": "orders"
  }
}
```

With this setup, when I insert a document on first VM's collection, it is reflecting in either 2nd or 3rd VM's DB. Not on both. What am I missing here? I want the insert on first VM to be reflected on both 2nd and third MongoDB's also. I don't want replication setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name should be different. Then it works well. Thanks. Closing this ticket.